# Keeping a sentence in the same tense

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses

What is the general rule behind mixing tenses in sentences such as this:

"He said he **was** hungry" versus "He said he **is** hungry"

My colleague thinks you can't say the latter because "said" and "is" are in different tenses. But I think the first sentence risks confusing the situation completely as it can possibly imply that he he *was* hungry but is not anymore. The second sentence I think implies that he was hungry and probably still is.

Comment: It depends entirely on context. *Is* he still hungry—or is he no longer? Without knowing anything, the first sentence is by far the more common. But you can't criticize either unless you know the actual facts being described. (Both are syntactically correct.)

Comment: In this case let's just say we don't know. It's something he said, then he disappeared out presumably to get something to eat.

Comment: If you don't know for sure that he is still hungry, then use the past tense. Or put it in quotes: He said, "I am hungry."

Comment: @JasonBassford Even if he meant now, you would say "He said he would be hungry now".

Answer (score 3):

I think if "he" is still currently hungry, then it's acceptable to phrase it that way.

What did he say?
He said he is hungry.

Answer (score 0):

When reporting past speech, we generally only use the present tense to describe a general, permanent condition, e.g.

> He said he is tall.

or

> He said he is hungry all the time.

If they're talking about a condition occurring at the time of the speech, we stay in the past tense:

> He said he was hungry, so he got a snack.